# How to handle milions of separate insert queries

Tags: mysql, command-line-interface, batch-processing

I have a situation in which I have to insert over 10 million separate records into one table. Normally a batch insert split into chunks does the work for me. The problem however is that this over 3gig file contains over 10 million separate insert statements. Since every query takes 0.01 till 0.1 seconds, it will take over 2 days to insert everything.

I'm sure there must be a way to optimize this by either lowering the insert time drasticly or somehow import in a different way.

I'm now just using the cli

```
source /home/blabla/file.sql
```

Note: It's a 3th party that is providing me this file. I'm

**Small update**
I removed any indexes

Comment: Is a full programming language an option?

Comment: You mean to parse the file into multiple bulks?

Comment: What i meant is, for example, the possibility of prepared statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drop the indexes, then re-index when you are done!

Comment: This helped me a bit. There must be more of these small tweaks to speed things up a bit.

Comment: My statement is not so much a small tweak. Think about exactly what the database has to do to insert data. Make that process as simple as possible! Does the database have to write every commit to disk now? That will take ages. Can that be turned off? It can. http://www.pythian.com/blog/mysql-set-global-innodb-fasttrue/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can parse the file data and combine several INSERT queries to one query like this:

```
INSERT INTO tablename (field1, field2...) VALUES (val1, val2, ..), (val3, val4, ..), ...
```

Comment: Its indeed one of my options, but I still see it as a fallback. I want the mysql server to do the trick without any other parsing process in for example PHP.

Comment: @ChrisVisser if you can execute the server/bash/shell commands you can try this one to insert the lines: mysql -h hostname -u user --password=password databasename < filename

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways to improve the speed of your `INSERT` statements:

- Try to insert many rows at once if this is an option.
- An alternative can be to insert the data into a copy of your desired table without indexes, insert the data there, then add the indexes and rename your table.
- Maybe use [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html), if this is an option.

The MySQL manual has [something to say about that](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-speed.html), too.

Comment: I normally use bulk scripts. In this case it's not possible to create a query since the 10 million queries are already there.

Comment: It shouldn't be that hard to convert statements like `INSERT INTO tablename (field1, field2...) VALUES (a, b, ..); INSERT INTO tablename (field1, field2...) VALUES (c, d, ..);` to something like `INSERT INTO tablename (field1, field2...) VALUES (a, b, ..), (c, d, ...);` or just extract the values and put them into a csv for a `LOAD DATA INFILE...` - but since no example is given it is only guesswork.